# Getting custom submit button (image button) to line up with text input?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, imagebutton, search-box

[image: See how the button does not line up]
I am attempting to implement a custom search button by using an image button. In the image above, you can see the problem I am running into. I have searched many threads about this topic but cannot get mine fixed. Below is the css code contain both the text input (search input) and the image button (green image button). Any and all help is appreciated.

CSS:

```
#search{
    position: absolute;
    right: 350px;
    top: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Html:

```
<div id='search'>
    <form action='searchquestions.php' method='post' >
    <input type='text' name='searchValue' placeholder='search'>
    <input type='image' src='searchbtn.png' alt='Submit' name='searchSubmit' height='20' width='20'>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your html markup. Also is #search the name of the container, the input, or the button?

Comment: #search is the div container

Comment: This needs source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this fiddle and see is this what you need

http://jsfiddle.net/94X8S/1/

```
#search input[type="image"]{
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
}
```